How to run GitLab CICD template (with .pre and .post stages) in parallel in the same stage but with different variables and tags
Full context: I have two branches in my Gitlab repo, let's call them dev and prd. In a feature branch or in dev I should be able to deploy to 3 environments (dev, tst, acc) and in a MR to prd i should be able to deploy to prd. I want to have a certain set of stages run independently for each environment. This stage comes from a trigger stage (but open to change it if needed)
In my current pipeline I need to use an external template to provide some authentication and cleanup before I run the actual steps, so the template will be something like:
# template.yml 

auth:
  stage: .pre
  # do authentication here

cleanup:
  stage: .post
  # do cleanup here

And in my actual CICD file I call this with include and run a couple more stages. This works fine if I only had one environment, but I'd like to be able to run everything in parallel like the following image:
ideal CICD pipeline
It's important that the same runner runs all stages for each env, so we need to pass the tags and the variables that are respective to each env.
The closest I've got was to extend the auth from the template, and then use anchors for all stages, but it still created an unwanted auth and cleanup stage:
not ideal CICD pipeline
